# Как обновить service не перезапуская его?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

Возможно ли такое, чтобы запускать сервис при запуске приложения, а затем после каких-либо операций на `UI` обновлять сервис без его перезапуска (т.е. сервис работает с начальными данными, затем пользователь что-то делает, данные передаются в сервис и он начинает работать уже с новыми данными, не делая при этом `stopService()`, `startService`) ?

Comment: Думаю, что в идеале перезапускать, передавая в конструктор новые параметры. Но если же Вас такое не устраивает, то по идее можно данные, которые вводит пользователь, хранить в статических переменных или в sharedPreferences, которые в свою очередь используются в вашем Service-классе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно.

При первом запуске сервиса вызывается его метод `onCreate`.
При каждом последующем вызове `Context#startServise(Context ctx, Intent intent)`, при условии, что сервис уже запущен, вызовется его метод `onStartCommand`.

Таким образом по умолчанию вы получаете нужное вам поведение и не сервис не перезапускается каждый раз при вызове `startServise`, а вызываете метод ранее созданного экземпляра класса.

При этом вы можете через содержимое интента передавать к-л данные, обновляя содержимое полей класса сервиса.

---

Также есть ещё механизм биндинга сервиса к активити, позволяющего в активити получить ссылку на экземпляр запущенного сервиса и напрямую вызывать методы его экземпляра примерно так: `instanceOfServiceClass.someMethodInServiceClass(someArgument);`. Загуглить можно по `Android service Binder`. Вот статья на русском: [Service. Биндинг. ServiceConnection](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection)

Comment: А как на счет быстродействия? Вызов `Context#startServise(Context ctx, Intent intent)` быстрее, чем останавливать и запускать сервис?

Comment: @Александр, я не мерил, конечно, но на 95% уверен что да, быстрее. И зачем его перезапускать, если можно обновить?.. Кстати, есть ещё механизм биндинга сервиса к активити, позволяющего в активити получить ссылку на экземпляр запущенного сервиса и напрямую вызывать методы его экземпляра. Гуглить `Android service Binder`

Comment: это хорошая вещь, используя `Binder` все равно нужно вызывать `Context#startServise(Context ctx, Intent intent)` ?

Comment: @Александр, да, изначально, хотя бы раз, сервис надо запустить стандартно. После этого подключиться к нему через `Binder`.

Comment: Где можно почитать подробнее про `Context#startServise(Context ctx, Intent intent)` ?

Comment: если можно, ссылку с примером :)

Comment: @Александр, [Service. Биндинг. ServiceConnection](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection)

Comment: что означает `#` в `Context#startServise(Context ctx, Intent intent)` ?

Comment: @Александр, это просто такая запись... В реальном коде заменяется точкой и означает, что  `startService` является методом класса `Context`

Comment: понятно, я так и подумал, но решил уточнить ) спасибо за подсказки )